# How do I calculate Mulligan probability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building, probability, mtg-manabase, mulligans

I am playing a game of Commander and I have a deck of 99 cards. In this deck are 37 lands. Using a hypergeometric calculator it returned a 29.12% chance of drawing exactly 3 Lands on a 7 card draw using the probability density function. My question is how do I calculate the probability for drawing 3 lands with one or more mulligans?

Comment: Which mulligan rule are you using?

Comment: @LeppyR64 I think we should assume the default Commander rules as specified in the CR unless a poster specifies otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

**The probability to draw exactly 3 lands after *n* attempts (including your first non-mulligan draw) is 1-(1-0.2912)^n, with n<6. With the maximum of 4 mulligans, you have a ~82.1% chance to get a 3-lander.**

On each mulligan, you draw a new hand of 7 cards and then put as many cards on the bottom of the library as you have taken mulligans.

> 103.4. Each player draws a number of cards equal to their starting hand size, which is normally seven. (Some effects can modify a player’s starting hand size.) A player who is dissatisfied with their initial hand may take a mulligan. First, the starting player declares whether they will take a mulligan. Then each other player in turn order does the same. Once each player has made a declaration, all players who decided to take mulligans do so at the same time. **To take a mulligan, a player shuffles the cards in their hand back into their library, draws a new hand of cards equal to their starting hand size, then puts a number of those cards equal to the number of times that player has taken a mulligan on the bottom of their library in any order.** [..]

This limits you to a maximum of 4 mulligans because if you take 5 or more, you will have fewer than 3 cards left in your starting hand and you can never have a 3-lander.

Also, since you shuffle the library between mulligans, the attempts are independent of each other.

If you have an event A with probability P(A), the probability of it failing is its inverse, or

> 1-P(A)

If you want to calculate the odds of *n* independent instances of A having at least 1 success, you first calculate the odds of *all* of them failing. Since the attempts are independent of each other in your case, you can simply multiply their probabilities with each other to get the result:

> (1-P(A))^n

The inverse of that is the probability that at least one of them does not fail:

> 1-(1-P(A))^n

That means that if you have seen n=5 hands (after 4 mulligans), the probability of having at least one of them being a 3-lander is

> 1 - (1-0.2912)^5 = 1 - 0.7088^5 = 1 - 0.1789 = 0.8211, or 82.1%

Comment: Does this analysis include the fact that the first mulligan in Commander is free? ("103.4c  In a multiplayer game and in any Brawl game, the first mulligan a player takes doesn’t count toward the number of cards that player will put on the bottom of their library or the number of mulligans that player may take.")

Comment: No. Only Brawl has the free mulligan, and the question makes no mention of Brawl.

Comment: Commander has a free mulligan "In a multiplayer game"; the Brawl reference is there because Brawl is two player.

Comment: The question makes no mention of multiplayer either.

Comment: 99% of Commander games are a 4 player pod. Yes, 1v1 Commander exists but it is very much _not_ what people mean when they say "Commander".

Answer (score -1):

37% times the 7 cards you initially draw gives you an average of 2.59 lands per opening hand for 40 lands you get 40% * 7 which gives you 2.8 lands on average. It seems you would need a 43% of lands in your deck to get a 3 lands opener on average. That means 26 lands for a 60 card deck and 37 for a commander deck.